# No file or directory exists: Path Varaible Setting

Tags: path, ubuntu-16.04, wxwidgets

I run a program which gives me error `./main: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_core-3.1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have a `libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so` file to which I am setting the path in `~./bashrc` file by adding the following two lines `

```
> $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"/home/saad/PathFiles" 
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

When I open the terminal again I get the error `bash: :/home/saad/PathFiles: No such file or directory` even though `libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so` is present in the PathFiles folder. Even after doing `sudo ldconfig` I get the No such file or directory error.

Comment: try to run ``which wx-config` and post the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line uses wrong syntax. If your `libwx_*.so` files are actually in `/home/saad/PathFiles`, you should just do

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/saad/PathFiles
```

or, if you have an existing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` value

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/saad/PathFiles:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You can also use `ldd ./main` to check whether all the dependencies are found.